# как выводить на консоль максимальный элемент массива в цикле

Tags: массивы, kotlin, циклы, for, arraylist

```
fun main() {
    var n = 10
    var a = IntArray(n){(Math.random()*10).toInt()}
    println(a.joinToString())
    for (i in 1..n-1) {
        if (a[i-1]>a[i] && a[i]<a[i+1]) {
            println(i.max) // <- здесь я не могу вывести максимальный элемент 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну вы пытаетесь максимум от числа i вывести. Но в целом не понятно, какой именно максимум вы пытаетесь вывести (максимум на текущий момент или что?)

Comment: я хотел найти максимум из локальных минимума

Answer (score 0):

Просто создай переменную , на первой итерации приравниваешь к n1 , потом сравниваешь.В конце выводи переменную

Answer (score 0):

вот тут несколько методов решения https://www.techiedelight.com/ru/find-minimum-maximum-element-array-kotlin/

Либо вот готовая реализация двумя методами

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val n = 10
    val array = IntArray(n){ (Math.random() * 10).toInt() }
    println(array.joinToString())

    //Проще сделать через List
    val massiveInList = array.toList()
    println("Maximum: ${massiveInList.max()}")

    //Если нужно именно через массив
    var maximum = 0

    for (i in 1 until n - 1) {
        if (array[i] > maximum) {
            maximum = array[i]
        }
    }

    println(maximum)
}
```